# How to print the $_REQUEST that is available inside a specific AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm a beginner in PHP, and I'm having some trouble debugging AJAX, because I can't just print_r what I want to know inside the script.

I'm using a AJAX image upload plugin that have a lot of functions such as receive post, file check, etc, to finally get to the "insertTodatabase" funcion. I want to know what data is being sent to this final fuction, how can I echo the $_REQUEST of such function, for example?

I'm sorry if my question is vague, I'm doing my best to explain.
Thank you.

Comment: Use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools for an easy way to see what data is being sent and received. [Here's how to do it in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function to write data to your error log. Then just view your error log and you can have the information stored there.

Example:

```
error_log('UserName: ' . $username);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I had to make a small change to error_log though, as it wasn't showing up at first. I'll leave it here for future searches: `error_log($username, 3, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\error.log'); // the parameter "3" specifies where to create the log`